# Get value of JS var in php

Tags: javascript, php

I want to be able to get the values of item1 to item5 passed to php. Following is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var item1 = 25;
var item2 = 12;
var item3 = 22;
var item4 = 45;
var item5 = 75;
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src ="mypage.php?myname=homer&age=27"> </script>
```

This code will be placed on the page. I want to access all the values of item1 to item5 along with myname and myage that is passed with the URL. I don't want to use AJAX nor can i place the script in any div.

Comment: Why don't you want to use ajax? You cannot send data from the client (javascript) to the server (PHP) without 1) reloading the page or 2) using asynchronous communication (AJAX)

Comment: By the time that the javascript runs, the PHP is done running (php is run by the server; javascript is run by the browser). Hence, you either need to code the php functionality in javascript, or you need to use ajax. There is no way around it.

Comment: Why accept **I don't want to** when it's easily enough accomplished with AJAX?

Comment: Say i want to display an iFrame with the item1 = height and item2=width. I get the content of iFrame from mypage.php. But i want to use some attributes of the var item1 to item5. I apologise as the var list of the first script is : 

`code
<script type="text/javascript">
var item1 = 25;
var item2 = 12;
var item3 = 22;
var item4 = 45;
var item5 = 75;
</script>
`

Comment: i think I will go with AJAX .. thanks all for your suggestions .. and thanks to all who downvoted a question . lol.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is creating the script tag in javascript and adding it to the DOM:

```
<script>
var s = document.createElement("script");
s.type = "text/javascript";
s.src = "mypage.php?myname=homer&age=27&item1=" + item1 + "&item2=" + item2; // etc
document.body.appendChild(script);
</script>
```